# Run a javascript function async, using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

This test works, but is there a better way than loading an empty file, to run an async javascript function?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "empty.dat", // empty file

    success: function(){
        doSomething(); // function to be run   
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: When do you want to run your JS function ?

Comment: @kmas I want to be able to call doSomething() from another function, to have it run in the background

Comment: Then @Phylogenesis 's answer seems correct.

Comment: there is a property async: true for the ajax request. do you want something like that?

Comment: @V31 it's async default. My code works, but I must fetch that empty file at server for it to work

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the browsers you need to target, you can use any of `setTimeout(fn, 0)`, `setImmediate(fn)` or [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers).

Comment: Most browsers, except for IE... Will try that! Thanks